# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'wantedids' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

In console showed me an error that parameters dictionary contains a null entry fo parameter `wantedids`,
So I wanted to pass checked boxes to my controller using array, so only admin can check all boxes of tips for specific user, admin have more than 5 users, In my console i succesfully pass an checked elements but it only showed me an error after that `Internal server error`. How can I pass that so I can update my database with checked boxes, can someone help.

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="cktips" idtips="@item.idtips 
    checked="@(item.iduser == ViewBag.iduser ? true : false)"/>
```

.js
var wantedids = [];

```
    $("#btnClick").click(function () {
        $(".cktips").each(function () {
         $(this).prop('checked', true);
         ids.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
        url: UrlSettingsDocument.Tips,
        data: { ids: ids},
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
        alert('successs');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
       }
     })
    })
```

Here is my Controller.cs

```
public JsonResult Statics(bool ids,int iduser,int idtips)
    {
        try
            {
                if (ids)
                {
                    statics = new statics ();
                    st.idtips= idtips;
                    Database.statics .Add(st);
                    Database.SaveChanges();
                }
            else if (!ids)
            {
                var stdelete= Database.statics.Where(a => a.iduser == iduser &&
                a.idtips== idtips).FirstOrDefault();
                Database.statics.Remove(stdelete);
                Database.SaveChanges();
            }
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Malinovski99,which line makes such error?Did you pass to backend successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Your wanted IDs seem to be a bool, but you're posting an array of values.
What are the IDs data type? are they int? make it `int[] wantedids`

not convinced `val()` is the right jquery for a checkbox anyways. Do you mean to get the value from idtips?

And are you passing data for the other parameters in your ajax post data block?

Update:

You are only passing one parameter to the post:

`data: { wantedids: wantedids},`

However your method has more than one parameter

`Statics(bool wantedids,int iduser,int idtips)`

where do these others get set, since they are not nullable `int?` then they must be provided (unless they're set as a route parameter?)

Comment: IDs data is type of int, i try that before with `int[] wantedids`, what do you mean for other parameters in ajax post?

Comment: Your controller method Statistics needs 3 params. You only pass one. Where are you passing iduser and idtips from?